# How can I install font T1 from ecrm1200 using Tex Live Manager (tlmgr)

Tags: fonts, texlive, mac

I'm using TexLive on OSX and having trouble compiling my TeX file with the error:

```
! I can't find file `ecrm1200'.
```

...

```
fontenc.sty:100: Font T1
/cmr/m/n/12=ecrm1200 at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found
```

which suggests I'm missing a `ecrm1200.tfm` file from somewhere.

However, searching for the file using the Tex Live Package Manager (`tlmgr`) like so

```
tlmgr search --file ecrm1200.tfm
```

does not produce any packages with this file in. What should I do?

Comment: Which TeX distribution are you using? Clearly not the whole TeX Live, since it contains the `ec` package.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned - I'm using the Basics package and was hoping to just install the packages I need to save on disk space.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `tlmgr` package is `ec`; however it's better to install the whole

```
collection-fontsrecommended
```

collection. Use TeX Live Utility, rather than the command line.

Better yet, install the full MacTeX and update frequently.

Comment: Thank you - installing `collection-fontsrecommended` fixed it (although installing just `ec` did not). Full MacTeX is nice but I only use a fraction of what Latex is capable of and need to conserve disk space on my laptop. Unfortunately the Tex Live utility does not work with MacTex Basics as it does not include Perl/Tk.

Comment: In Fedora 22 it is the package `texlive-collection-fontsrecommended`

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the accepted answer, I should point out that the reason the search command was failing is that `tlmgr` by default searches the local installation rather than the remote mirror.

To find a missing file, the search command should instead by used with the `--global` switch:

```
$ tlmgr search --global --file ecrm1200.tfm
```

Giving the result

```
tlmgr: package repository       
http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet
ec:
    texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/jknappen/ec/ecrm1200.tfm
```